# Simplest C++ test framework that works with jenkins

Tags: c++, unit-testing, jenkins

I am looking for a simple test framework that can output readable by Jenkins. It needs to work with MSVC 6 and 2010. Hopefully something that can be compiled with the project, like a few header files or so. Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Jenkins QA Stack / Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271465/c-jenkins-qa-stack-tools)

Comment: Also, [boost::test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537914/using-jenkins-with-boost-test-unit-tests).

Comment: I'd say any testing framework that is able to output test results in junit XML format can be integrated with jenkins.

Comment: Will have a look at boost, the C++ Jenkins QA stack mentions CppUnit, that is just a bit to big for me now. I want to do a simple example for training purpose and I would like to include some unit testing if it is simple.

Comment: CATCH - we use it, it's header only. Any fail message is wonderfully precise. https://github.com/philsquared/Catch

Comment: I found [google test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) easier to use than cppunit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CATCH](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch)! That's what I was looking for. In 5 minutes I have it up and running. Just what I was looking for. Thanks to doctorlove!